# Content falls behind fixed navbar and won't get pushed down

Tags: html, css, sass, pug

Good evening all. I'm trying to make a website with a fixed navbar. 
The result I'm trying to achieve is a bit different than what you'll see in my [CodePen](https://codepen.io/make96/pen/dmegJN)

In my example I'm trying to position the *h1* element bellow the *navbar*, but I can't seem to make it work. I've tried using *z-index* like others have suggested in similar posts, but I don't see any changes.

```
nav
 .box
  #nav-icon1
   span
   span
   span
   span
 ul
  li
   a(href="#") Despre
  li
   a(href="#") FAQ
  li
   a(href="#") Numere
  li
   a(href="#") Colectiv
h1 test
```

SASS

```
body
 height: 2000px
 nav
  border: 1px solid black
  width: 100vw
  margin: 0 auto
  position: fixed
  ul
   text-align: center
   font-size: 0 // I'm using this to eliminate the space between the li elements
  li
   display: inline-block
   padding: 3vh 6vw
   &:hover
    cursor: pointer
    a
     font-size: calc(20px + (30 - 20) * ((100vw - 300px) / (1600 - 300)))
     text-decoration: none
     color: gray
 h1
  font-size: 50px
```

Comment: do you want to make h1 fixed below the nav bar?

Comment: Yes, I want to position it below the navbar and stay there when I scroll

Comment: As you have fixed position for `nav`, there is no meaning for `below` except you make the `h1` also fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
please take a look of edited code for h1

    body
  height: 2000px
  nav
    border: 1px solid black
    width: 100vw
    margin: 0 auto
    position: fixed
    ul
      text-align: center
      font-size: 0
      li
        display: inline-block
        padding: 3vh 6vw
        &:hover
          cursor: pointer
        a
          font-size: calc(20px + (30 - 20) * ((100vw - 300px) / (1600 - 300)))
          text-decoration: none
          color: gray
h1
  padding-top: 10vh
  font-size: 50px
  position: fixed
  left: 0
```

edited code pen  [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wmjQEv)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend doing something like this if you can give your nav bar a set height. Can be fairly common to offset your page content with a margin-top equivalent to the same height as the fixed nav/header. And don't just offset the h1, offset a content wrapper class so you can continue to add all the content in there.

PUG/HTML

`nav
  .box
    #nav-icon1
      span
      span
      span
      span
  ul
    li
      a(href="#") Despre
    li
      a(href="#") FAQ
    li
      a(href="#") Numere
    li
      a(href="#") Colectiv
div.content-wrapper
  h1 test`

SASS

`body
  height: 2000px
  nav
    border: 1px solid black
    width: 100vw
    margin: 0 auto
    position: fixed
    top: 0
    height: 80px
    ul
      text-align: center
      font-size: 0
      li
        display: inline-block
        padding: 3vh 6vw
        &:hover
          cursor: pointer
        a
          font-size: calc(20px + (30 - 20) * ((100vw - 300px) / (1600 - 300)))
          text-decoration: none
          color: gray

.content-wrapper
  margin-top: 80px
h1
  font-size: 50px`

If you can't set the height, you could write some javascript to get the height and programmatically set the margin-top.